# 8BitDo SN30 Pro Switch mode on 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, games, hardware

I currently have two of the SN30 Pro controllers that I'm trying to connect via Switch mode to utilize their motion controls in yuzu. I can connect them in Xinput mode via bluetooth just fine, and all the programs I use recognize them perfectly. When I try Switch mode (Y+start) it will not connect to the controller unless it is plugged in. Once I unplug the controller, it turns off immediately. I've already performed the `fwupd` process, as that's how I had to get it to connect bluetooth Xinput in the first place. Does anyone know how to use the motion control from these controllers another way or how to get Switch mode to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

once you enable switch mode you have to press the sync button behind your gamepad...the lights then will flash left and right.
is the only way to connect it via bluetooth.